# Error when using step option in jQuery .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#MainNavBar").animate({
        width: "48px"
    },
    1000,
    function () {
        console.log("complete!");
    }, {
        step: function (now, fx) {
            // var data = fx.elem.id + " " + fx.prop + ": " + now;
            // console.log(fx.prop);
            //  console.log(now);
        }
    });
```

which is working fine until I add in the step method.

When I add the step method as above I get the following error

> TypeError: m.easing[this.easing] is not a function

Now I have the jquery-ui included in the root layout file

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction and where I am going wrong please?

Answer (score 2):

The order of parameters to [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) is incorrect. The signature of `animate` you're using is

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

Here, it expects the third parameter as the name(string) of easing effect not a function. So, the error

> easing is not a function

Use:

```
$("#MainNavBar").animate({
    width: "48px"
}, {
    duration: 1000,
    step: function () {
        // Code here
    }
},
function () {
    console.log("complete!");
});
```

Comment: perfect, was scratching my head fo ages with this. its been a long day! :)

Comment: @MatthewFlynn Welcome! Glad to help :)